# Changing Font Colour and making text bold in TCL

Tags: fonts, colors, tcl

Is it possible to change colour of text and make it bold from TCL script and output it in console/terminal?

I found [this on example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25519393/how-to-change-color-text-using-puts-in-tcl) on the forum but I get following error:

*ERROR: couldn't execute "tput": no such file or directory
procedure "color" line 4:*

Wondered if someone can advise.

Thanks in advance,

Example from reference post (see link above), example provided by Donal Fellows

```
proc color {foreground text} {
    # tput is a little Unix utility that lets you use the termcap database
    # *much* more easily...
    return [exec tput setaf $foreground]$text[exec tput sgr0]
}

puts "Why not [color 4 G][color 1 o][color 3 o][color 4 g][color 2 l][color 1 e] first?"
# Hmm, that's clearer than using those escapes directly too!
```

Comment: please post your code.

Comment: added code, basically copy paste from link provided and also referenced author.

Comment: Thanks! which OS you are using ? Is that not linux ?

Comment: I'm using Windows 7, the referred post also mentions windows 7 so I was assuming it would work. Do I need additional tcl packages installed?

Comment: Above method `tput` works on linux. you may need use `twapi`. I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`tput` is a linux command which is part of the `ncurses` package. if you are not using any linux flavours OR ncurses package is not installed properly- you will get this error.
So if you are using

**linux-**
check ncurses library is installed or not.

**windows:-**

Its better use `twapi` package.

Install twapi.

```
teacup install twapi
```

Try below in tclsh.

```
# Import package twapi
package require twapi

# Get handler of console
set hndl [twapi::get_console_handle stdout]

# Set console foreground color to red
twapi::_set_console_default_attr $hndl fgred 1
```

Refer this [link1](https://community.activestate.com/node/6621)[link2](http://wiki.tcl.tk/16659)

Comment: is there anyway I can use this without installing twapi i.e pure tcl, cause I will share my scripts with other users and would they also have to install twapi?

Comment: @Stergio The `twapi` package is compiled code (I can't remember if it is C or C++). If you share your scripts, you'll need to tell them to install the package. Or you can build a starkit (single-file distribution) with it included. The doing of that is probably covered by other questions already, but it might be worth asking as a separate Q anyway so as to explicitly cover getting twapi into it.